# AJAX Get request overflow the number in JavaScript

Tags: java, ajax, rest

Hi I am using a REST API which returns me JSON object. One of the JSON's property is user's ID which on the server side is stored like number (the server  logic is written in Java so it's probably `Long`). Some of the Ids are too big and the response I get with AJAX request is not accurate.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I am doing this on the front-end with standard jquery ajax request.